# Morally, should I resign early to save someone else from being laid off?

Tags: resignation, layoff

I manage a team of 5, and my company needs to downsize it to 4. 
I have been planning to leave my job in a couple months time (moving overseas), but no one know this. Me leaving early would likely mean that no one needed to be laid off.

There is one obvious person to lay off, but this is no reflection of their work.  This person is a good worker and has a very young family (2 kids under 3yrs).

I feel bad about laying him off, considering that I already plan to leave and would be ok with resigning earlier.

Morally, should I resign early to save this person's job?

Comment: Do you have another job to go to?

Comment: No, because I am moving overseas, back to my home country

Comment: The most important question: is there someone in your current team who is an ideal candidate to take over your position? Not someone who'd be merely acceptable or competent or is good at his current job, but someone who would be the best person for your position even if you  were interviewing external candidates. If there isn't then you leaving doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah there is someone in my opinion. I'm not sure if the company feels the same.  They could promote this person to my position.

Comment: Instead of resigning early, do you think you can give notice for several months away without being pushed out? In this situation it makes more sense to contact your management, announce your plans to leave and suggest this person from your team as a replacement. The main risk is that they terminate your employment sooner or immediately but you're best placed to judge how they will react.

Comment: Note that this question is borderline off-topic as too opinion based and your ethical responsibility is hugely dependent on the particulars of the situation: the company's reaction to early notice, impact of an early resignation on your finances, how likely it is that your resignation will have the intended effect, etc. I'm having a hard time picturing comprehensive answers that aren't a page long.

Comment: My concern would be that your company could just decide to lay the other person off anyways.  Unless you could get some sort of guarantee that this wouldn't happen, I have a feeling you may be disappointed with the outcome if you leave.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Questions of morality are always going to be partly opinion based, but if you actually have hard plans in place to move and it's simply a question of altering timings by a few weeks, then you should at least consider approaching your seniors; tell them the position and see if they will consider deferring the layoff.

Present it as an economic decision - having an extra member of staff for one more month is clearly going to be cheaper than laying someone off (with the legal costs), then hiring your replacement and training them up, especially if there is a risk that the victim will not come back to fill the gap willingly - either he gets a job elsewhere in the meantime, or takes the news sufficiently badly that his trust in your company is broken.

Comment: If you tell your company you are leaving, there always is a risk they'll fire you on the spot. Especially when it's an economic decision: they might need to reduce spendings NOW, so it's either fire him or fire you.

Comment: Or fire you first, fire him later.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that your company has a lot more money than you do. If you give up your job now to help someone, that's your money gone, and there is no guarantee that it will even help another employee. Instead your company could keep employing that person; they will benefit from it (because he will continue doing work from the company) whereas you have no benefit. And they have more money than you do.

So no, morally there is no reason whatsoever not to put your own interest first. How hard would you kick yourself if you gave up your job, then ran into some financial problem which means you can't take off to your home country, and then they fire that guy anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Morals are a personal code of conduct that you've adopted.  No one but you and your clergy can advise you on morality.

Ethically, I think you are on the right track.  If you are a manager, a private 2-month warning to your director is probably a good idea, but it depends on your relationship with the company.

If you have a good relationship, talk with your director about your concerns.  If I were he (no gender inferred, but just for convenience), the next thing I would ask you is if you feel any member of your team is ready to take over your role.  From his point of view, he can lose 1 person with knowledge of the operation, or two.  Training up new hires is a HUGE investment in time and resources.  Anything I can do to avoid that is worth considering.  2 months' salary of a line-level developer is pretty darned cheap compared to training up a new employee.